# How to cast RGB to float arrays in Python

Tags: python, casting, rgb, dtype

I have an image that I need to save into the RGB type described below.

```
RGB_DTYPE = np.dtype({'names': ['R', 'G', 'B'],
                  'formats': [np.uint8, np.uint8, np.uint8]})

x = get_image_from_jpg(in_fname)  # float 32 numpy array, with shape [128, 128, 3]
x = do_some_computation(x)  # do some computation before saving
x_rgb = x.astype(RGB_DTYPE)  # RGB dtype to save the image into the right format
save_rgb_image(x_rgb, out_fname)  # save the image on the disk
```

After that, when I load the image from the disk, I need to convert it to float32 to run computations with standard Python libraries.

```
x_rgb = load_rgb_image(out_fname)  # load image 
print(x_rgb.dtype)  # returns: [('R', 'u1'), ('G', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1')]
x = x_rgb.astype(np.float32)  # --> ERROR
```

However, I get the following error, which I don't understand how to solve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype([('R', 'u1'), ('G', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1')]) to dtype('float32') according to the rule 'unsafe'
```

Any idea what this is and how to solve it?

Comment: There are two problems here. First, you have an array that you are trying to cast to scalar. The second problem is that the RGB values are `uint8`, so they will be in the range 0...255, but you need to convert that to float in the range of 0...1, so you you'll have to do some arithmetic (division) too.

Comment: thanks for the help. How do you think I can I solve problem #1?

Comment: it looks like you already have all `float32` data in the `x` variable in the first chunk of code you've shown. so why don't you use floats in your `RGB` type?

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot do it, because it would occupy too much memory on the disk

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution! The RGB dtype array must be treated as a structured numpy array. Thus, the conversion is possible using `.view()` as:

```
def cast_structured_array_to_array(x_rgb):
    """ convert structured array to standard array """
    x = x_rgb.view((x_rgb.dtype[0], len(x_rgb.dtype.names)))
    x = np.squeeze(x)
    return x
```

And then, you can convert the array to the desired type as `x.astype(np.float32)`.